# Why does Roe Average use enthalpy?

Tags: cfd

If my understanding is correct, Roe averaging is supposed to be a linearization of the nonlinear flux jacobian.  For the Euler equations, one can compute the roe average as depending on density, velocity, and enthalpy.

Why is it enthalpy?  How would I derive that from a parameter vector approach, and how would I compute a different roe average for a system that is fundamentally different from the Euler equations?